# How to write binary data to stdout in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 2.x I could do this:

```
import sys, array
a = array.array('B', range(100))
a.tofile(sys.stdout)
```

Now however, I get a `TypeError: can't write bytes to text stream`. Is there some secret encoding that I should use?

Comment: It would be much better to find an answer that will work with Python 2.6+ and 3.x

Comment: `os.write` will work on both Py2 and Py3.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

A better way:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"some binary data")
```

Comment: Using `sys.stdout.buffer` also lets you do things like using `shutil.copyfileobj` even when the source file object gives bytes, and not strings. +1

Comment: Programs using this can't be tested in IDLE 3: `AttributeError: 'PseudoOutputFile' object has no attribute 'buffer'`

Comment: @DamianYerrick in IDLE (in Windows at least) `pythonw.exe` runs IDLE, which means that there is no stdout. It is emulated with tkinter. It physically can't handle bytes. In this case, `.decode('UTF-8', errors='replace')` your string, or run `python3 -I <filename>` to get a REPL instead of using IDLE.

Comment: Messes up order of writes when writing to `stderr` if using along with `print(file=sys.stderr)`.

Comment: @Kotauskas are you calling flush after writing?

Comment: buffer.flush() doesn't seems to work, no way to write unbuffered binary.

Comment: @VincentAlex ```sys.stdout.flush()```

Answer (score 22):

An idiomatic way of doing so, which is only available for Python 3, is:

```
with os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), "wb", closefd=False) as stdout:
    stdout.write(b"my bytes object")
    stdout.flush()
```

The good part is that it uses the normal file object interface, which everybody is used to in Python.

Notice that I'm setting `closefd=False` to avoid closing `sys.stdout` when exiting the `with` block. Otherwise, your program wouldn't be able to print to stdout anymore. However, for other kind of file descriptors, you may want to skip that part.

Comment: Why do you flush? Isn't it better to let Python decide when to flush stdout?

Comment: Can't the existing channel -- such as `sys.stdout` -- be somehow turned into binary mode (and then back) without opening a new one on top of it?

Comment: I don't think so. BTW I flush because otherwise the fd will be closed. Maybe python would flush anyways... you can try and report.

Comment: `sys.stdout.buffer` is in binary mode

Comment: "Notice that I'm setting closefd=False to avoid closing sys.stdout when exiting the with block. " Is it actually valid to re-open it when it's already open, though?

Answer (score 19):

```
import os
os.write(1, a.tostring())
```

or, `os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), …)` if that's more readable than `1` for you.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Feels a bit hack-ish but I guess it's not that common thing to do.

Comment: The problem with `os.write` is that you'll have to check the return value, as it doesn't guarantee that everything will be written.

Answer (score 3):

In case you would like to specify an encoding in python3 you can still use the bytes command like below:

```
import os
os.write(1,bytes('Your string to Stdout','UTF-8'))
```

where 1 is the corresponding usual number for stdout --> sys.stdout.fileno()

Otherwise if you don't care of the encoding just use:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Your string to Stdout\n")
```

If you want to use the os.write without the encoding, then try to use the below:

```
import os
os.write(1,b"Your string to Stdout\n")
```

Comment: Programs using `os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), some_bytes)` won't work in IDLE. `io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno`

Comment: @DamianYerrick: You are right...the IDLE should not be used anyway to test something like that. Shortly: try to open the IDLE (I had the python3.5.1 shell) and simply import sys      and     sys.stdout.fileno()      it will throw you io error, because in IDLE this is not supported operation :-) It is always important to remember in which environment you are working and try to get what is possible ;) Hope this clarify your query :-) Have a nice weekend.

Comment: You only mention one way of writing actual binary data to `stdout`, the last one.