# response.body is returning an empty file using scrapy in python

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to make a web crawler, using scrapy from python, that extracts the information that google shows in the right side when you make a search

The URL I am using is: https://www.google.com/search?q=la%20cuarta

In this other question I asked the same ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56172524/following-the-information-using-scrapy-in-nested-div-and-span-tags?noredirect=1#comment99204908_56172524)), someone suggested me to write response.body to a file, but I am getting an empty file, when I tried a different URL this does not happend

This is my code:

```
import scrapy

class google1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'google1'

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        'https://www.google.com/search?q=la%20cuarta',
        'https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html']  
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'page-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

It does not even write the file from the google search, but in the scrapy shell response.body is not empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I tested your code and it works, that is the spiders downloads all the pages, including the googel page.
Your problem might be in the settings, add these to your settings:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```