# how to create a data structure binary file in python?

Tags: python

I am working a image build project, I am trying to use python to create a structure,
I know c is very easy to create a data structure, here is a c example.

```
struct Books {
   char  title[50];
   char  author[50];
   char  subject[100];
   uint32_t book_id;
   uint8_t book_ver;
   uint16_t book_location;
};
 
void main( ) {
   FILE *fptr;
   struct Books Book1;        /* Declare Book1 of type Book */
 
   strcpy( Book1.title, "C Programming");
   strcpy( Book1.author, "Anna Ali"); 
   strcpy( Book1.subject, "C Programming Tutorial");
   Book1.book_id = 649507;
   Book1.book_ver = 2;
   Book1.book_location= 308;

   fptr = fopen("book_struct.bin","wb");
   fwrite(&Book1, sizeof(struct Books), 1, fptr); 
   fclose(fptr);     
}
```

How can I create a data struct binary file in python?
Can someone help to provide a python reference code?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092527/python-write-bytes-to-file?

Comment: no the right answer.