# How can i save the uploaded pdf file using Streamlit Python?

Tags: python, streamlit

I have created a form with multiple text input values and one pdf upload. But I also want to save the pdf file uploaded to one my directory folder , How can I do that?

```
st.title("Demo")
st.image(res, width = 800)

st.markdown("**Please fill the below form :**")
with st.form(key="Form :", clear_on_submit = True):
    Name = st.text_input("Name : ")
    Email = st.text_input("Email ID : ")
    File = st.file_uploader(label = "Upload Pic", type=["pdf","docx"])
    Submit = st.form_submit_button(label='Submit')
    

st.subheader("Details : ")
st.metric(label = "Name :", value = Name)
st.metric(label = "Email ID :", value = Email)

if Submit :
    st.markdown("**Pic Sucessfully Uploaded.**")
```

Comment: Are you using this locally?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this depends on where its being deployed.

Local machine (or server you have control of): Save it to anywhere you want on the local filesystem using the standard Python write mechanism:

```py
with open(filename, 'wb') as f: 
    f.write(filebytes)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70157307/2394542

Streamlit Cloud: because of the container deployment, you cannot guarantee that a specific container will be running, that multiple containers don't exist, etc. In this case, you should write to Google Drive, Amazon S3 or any other permanent location *outside* of Streamlit Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to save locally from a given folder the uploaded file.

```
import streamlit as st
from pathlib import Path


st.title("Demo")
# st.image(res, width = 800)

st.markdown("**Please fill the below form :**")
with st.form(key="Form :", clear_on_submit = True):
    Name = st.text_input("Name : ")
    Email = st.text_input("Email ID : ")
    File = st.file_uploader(label = "Upload file", type=["pdf","docx"])
    Submit = st.form_submit_button(label='Submit')
    

st.subheader("Details : ")
st.metric(label = "Name :", value = Name)
st.metric(label = "Email ID :", value = Email)

if Submit :
    st.markdown("**The file is sucessfully Uploaded.**")

    # Save uploaded file to 'F:/tmp' folder.
    save_folder = 'F:/tmp'
    save_path = Path(save_folder, File.name)
    with open(save_path, mode='wb') as w:
        w.write(File.getvalue())

    if save_path.exists():
        st.success(f'File {File.name} is successfully saved!')
```

Ref: [file_uploader](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.file_uploader)