# Output binary data from CGI in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi, binary-data

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/908331/554319). I was having no problems while printing raw binary data from a CGI script in Python 2, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(os.path.abspath('test.png'), 'rb') as f:
        print "Content-Type: image/png\n"
        print f.read()
```

Here are the relevant response headers:

```
> GET /cgi-bin/plot_string2.py HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
> Host: 0.0.0.0:8888
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 Script output follows
< Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.3.2
< Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2013 16:21:25 GMT
< Content-Type: image/png
```

and the result is interpreted as an image, as expected. However, if I try to make a translation to Python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(os.path.abspath('test.png'), 'rb') as f:
        print("Content-Type: image/png\n")
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(f.read())
```

Nothing is returned, and here are the headers:

```
> GET /cgi-bin/plot_string3.py HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
> Host: 0.0.0.0:8888
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 Script output follows
< Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.3.2
< Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2013 16:22:13 GMT
< �PNG
<
```

I cannot do `print(f.read())` anymore because that will print something like `b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00...`. The question I linked gives a solution, but apparently doesn't work in this environment.

Thoughts?

**Added**: [Note for the future](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4376072/554319):

> This also means `print` is no good for CGI any more.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `sys.stdout.flush` to force the header printed before the body:

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(os.path.abspath('test.png'), 'rb') as f:
        print("Content-Type: image/png\n")
        sys.stdout.flush() # <---
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(f.read())
```

Or remove print, and use `sys.stdout.buffer.write` only:

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(os.path.abspath('test.png'), 'rb') as f:
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"Content-Type: image/png\n\n") # <---
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(f.read())
```

**NOTE**

`f.read()` could cause a problem if the file is huge. To prevent that, use [`shutil.copyfileobj`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj):

```
import os
import shutil
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(os.path.abspath('test.png'), 'rb') as f:
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"Content-Type: image/png\n\n")
        shutil.copyfileobj(f, sys.stdout.buffer)
```

Comment: Omg thank you for this. Cannot believe how hard it was to get this to work