# Python cgi print image to html

Tags: python, html, image, cgi

How to print a png image to html?

I have:

```
print("Content-Type: image/png\n")
print(open('image.png', 'rb').read())
```

And it prints that:

```
Content-Type: image/png
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x0 ...
```

[That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791004/output-binary-data-from-cgi-in-python-3) answer didn't help me.
I have this:

```
Content-Type: image/png �PNG  IHDR�X��%sBIT|d�  pHYsaa�?�i IDAT...
```

HTTP Server:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: you need empty line between headers and data - so you need two `\n`. And you may need header with data size/length.

Comment: @furas It didn't change anything.

Comment: btw: you doesn't print to HTML but to HTTP body.

Comment: Now I see. `print` convert bytes into string but you have to send pure/original bytes without prefix `b""`.

Comment: @furas How can I do that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791004/output-binary-data-from-cgi-in-python-3a

Comment: @furas That didn't help either. I have now: `Content-Type: image/png �PNG  IHDR�X��%sBIT|d� pHYsaa�?�i IDATx� ...`

Comment: For you it looks strange but for browser it can be correct data. Did you try it in browser ?

Comment: @furas Yes, I try all of this in browser.

Comment: what server did you use ?

Comment: @furas HTTPServer

Comment: if you use `Python3` then you should use try `python3 -m http.server --cgi 8000`

Comment: @furas I have something on this page already, everything works except images. I use `from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()`

Comment: Put this in question - it will be more readable.

Comment: I'm not sure if we not go in wrong direction. This server can serve images directly - ie. in browser try `localhost:8000/image.png` - so you don't have to create all this code with `"Content-Type"`. If you want to see image in HTML then you have to use HTML tag `<img src="/image.png">`. Code with `"Content-Type"` is usefull if you need to serve dinamically created images.

Comment: @furas This `print("<img src='/image.png'>")` works. Previously I was trying without `/`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I created extended version: [Simple CGI Server with CGI scripts in different languages.](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/tree/master/CGI/simple-server-with-different-languages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** extended source code in [Simple CGI Server with CGI scripts in different languages](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/tree/master/CGI/simple-server-with-different-languages).

---

I have structure: (all code is at the end)

```
project
├── cgi-bin
│   └── image.py
├── image.png
├── index.html
└── server.py
```

and I run `./server.py` (or `python3 server.py`)

---

CGI server can serve images without extra code. You can try

```
http://localhost:8000/image.png
```

Or put tag in HTML (ie. in `index.html`)

```
< img src="/image.png" >
```

and run

```
http://localhost:8000/index.html
```

If you need dynamically created image then create folder `cgi-bin` with script ie. `image.py`
(on Linux you have to set execution attribute `chmod +x image.py`)

And then you can run this script directly

```
http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/image.py
```

or in HTML

```
< img src="/cgi-bin/image.py" >
```

---

**server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

server_address = ("", 8000)

httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

**cgi-bin/image.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os

src =  "image.png"
length = os.stat(src).st_size

sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: image/png\n")
sys.stdout.write("Content-Length: " + str(length) + "\n")
sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.buffer.write(open(src, "rb").read())
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>image.png</h1>
    <img src="/image.png">
    
    <h1>cgi-bin/image.py</h1>
    <img src="/cgi-bin/image.py">    
</body>

</html>
```

**image.png**

[image]