# Python return image to http request

Tags: python, image, printing

I setup python in iis with handler "c:...\python.exe %s %s" for *.py. Then want to provide url like "https://.../getpng.py?no=1" to return image stream to html  as below

```
<img src="https://.../getpng.py?no=1">
```

The getpng.py is simple as below.

```
with open('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\test\\test1.png', 'rb') as f:
    filecontent = f.read()

print('Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n')
print(filecontent )
```

The image path is correct. The filecontent is correct. But html page always shows broken image.
It looks like "print(filecontent)" failed. Any hints to solve this issue?

I tried sys.stdout.write but that did not work neither.

Also tried the following neither working
print('Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n' + filecontent )
print('Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n{0}'.format(filecontent ))

I tried the following.

```
with open('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\test\\test.png', 'rb') as f:
    abyte = f.read()
print('Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n')
sys.stdout.buffer.write (abyte)
f.close()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\testpng.py", line 59, in <module>
    test6()
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\testpng.py", line 56, in test6
    sys. stdout. buffer. write (abyte)
AttributeError: 'StdOutputFile' object has no attribute 'buffer'
```

- when run in browser http://localhost/test/testpng.py, returns broken image
- when run in Python IDE, returns error message as below

Does that mean the Python 3.10.8 has sys without stdout.buffer ?

Comment: What is the reason for the python script, why not show the image in html directly?

Comment: That image file is an example. In fact I generate such image dynamically, e.g. a dynamic QR code, that I want to return via url to browser.

Comment: In classic asp, I could do response.binarywrite to return the raw image to browser. But in python, the print does not act the same.

Comment: How should the bytecode be displayed into a html page? Use better [javeScript.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20756091/12621346) or [pyscript](https://pyscript.net/) or a easy way is convert the image to base64. Base64 could be displayed into html directly.

Comment: I want to make the http://....getpng.py url same as http://....png

Comment: When I use classic asp brinary.write to print a png file to browser, it looks like below

Comment: is this using `flask` or some framework? There is no context to your question and  no tag showing what you are using server-side.

Comment: No framework used in server side. Just use iis enable cgi to run Python on *.py.

Comment: You need to write binary data,  with `sys.stdout.buffer.write()`, @furas has the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40451727/2836621

Comment: Thanks. I tried the following: sys.ztdout.buffer.write(datacontent) where datacontent = file.read() from binary file, then python error like non text parameters. I am using latest 3.8.x.x which may have missed  binary conversation

Comment: Click `edit` and put your latest/greatest code in your question along with the exact error messages. The comments area is not good for code. Thanks.

Comment: You don't seem yo have used the example I linked? You didn't send the content length either?

Comment: I sent content length but made no difference in Print case. The problem is "no Buffer for stdout".

Comment: If the PNG file is bmp file, the Print works well

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 to show an image on a web page;

```
import base64

with open('QR.jpg', 'rb') as image_file:
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    #print(base64_bytes)

    base64_string = base64_bytes.decode()
    print(base64_string) # For insert into the img tag.
```

Than into the html:

```
<img src="
      data:image/jpeg;
      data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ....
      " alt="QR.jpg" />
```

Comment: Yes that is what I currently use and that work. But it in fact returnes html code with embed data. But I want to return a image to browser with content-type image/png so the url is considered as image resources. The difficult part is the how to response raw image data to browser