# How can I send a byte-object over a pipe in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pipe, python-3.6

I am trying to send a numpy array over stdout from one process to another.

Sending it over the pipe requires me to convert it to a string.
On the other side, I receive a byte object. This byte object now has the original byte string encapsulated.

I find it now impossible to restore the original byte object as a byte object.
If I decode the byte object, I receive a string which is incompatible with all the restoring functions I tried (np.frombuffer, pickle.loads).

server.py

```
import subprocess
import numpy as np
p = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'writer.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while 1:
    tmp = p.stdout.readline()    
    # doesn't fail but wrong size
    array = np.frombuffer(tmp, dtype=np.uint8)
    tmp = bytes.decode(tmp)
    # fails because byte object is necessary
    array = np.frombuffer(tmp, dtype=np.uint8)
    array = array.reshape([1, 3, 5, 5, 1])
    print(array.shape)
```

writer.py

```
import numpy as np
import sys
while 1:
    array = np.zeros([1, 3, 5, 5, 1], dtype=np.int8)
    string = array.tobytes()
    sys.stdout.write(str(string))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Is there anyway to convert the string into a byteobject, without encoding it? 
How else could this work?
I want to use pipes instead of shared memory as proposed in some other solutions to keep it more simple. Furthermore, I need it to be parallel but blocking, so Pipes seemed ideal to me.

Thanks

Comment: how about you first send the size of the object to come, then read that size from the buffer in the server?

Comment: @DanielSanchez I don't quite understand, there's no buffer on the server side? There's stdout from which I can read out everything that was sent. But reading the whole string is not the problem. I want to restore the original object.

Comment: @Kilsen have you tried in the writer `sys.stdout.write(string)` without converting to `str`?

Comment: @kazemakase Yes, this isn't possible because `stdout.write` requires a string

Comment: @Kilsen `sys.stdout.write(b'abc')` works for me. Why does it not work for you?

Comment: @kazemakase I am on python 3, this seems to work on python 2

Comment: @Kilsen I am on Python 3.5.2. Do you get an error message?

Comment: @kazemakase: weird:
`Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys

>>> sys.stdout.write(b'abc')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
>>> 
`

Comment: @Kilsen Doh! This seems to depend on the terminal backend used. Running in Spyder it worked, but running in the terminal it failed for me too. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/908440/3005167).

Comment: @kazemakase: thanks for your help! yes, stdout.buffer was what I was looking for.  When I tried using stdout.buffer.write I got an additional byte on the receiving side for some reason. ymonad's solution is working perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `pickle` to marshal the data, and `sys.stdout.buffer` instead of `sys.stdout` to write bytes to stdout.

Reference: [sys.stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout)

server.py:

```
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import pickle
p = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'writer.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while 1:
  array = pickle.load(p.stdout)
  array = array.reshape([1, 3, 5, 5, 1])
  print(array.shape)
```

writer.py:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import sys
while 1:
  array = np.zeros([1, 3, 5, 5, 1], dtype=np.int8)
  pickle.dump(array, sys.stdout.buffer)
```